# Django Testing Aggregate with sqlite3

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-testing

I'm doing some aggregates using Django querysets that are working fine against a MySQL backend. When I run the following code to aggregate across a queryset:

```
agg = myqueryset.values('name', 'category').annotate(Sum('quantity'))
```

Using MySQL, I get:

```
[{'name': u'My Name', 'category': 21L, 'quantity__sum': 10}]
```

When I run this same code using Django's TestCase or django-webtest against a sqlite3, in memory database, I get the following:

```
[{'name': u'My Name', 'category': 21, 'quantity__sum': 3}, {'name': u'My Name', 'category': 21, 'quantity__sum': 7}]
```

The only difference I can see is that category, which happens to be a FK, is reported as 21L when it's output using MySQL and just 21 when output during the sqlite3 test. Any ideas on why the aggregation isn't working with my tests but works fine when the same code is called from a view against MySQL?